# "The task of science,as we know , is to discover facts..."

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, passive-voice

"The task of science,as we know , is to discover facts; but a haphazard collection of facts cannot ______________________ a science "

According to my test book, the answer for the blank is that " **be said to constitute** "   but there was another option on the answers of the question which is " **be said that it constitutes** "

So I would like to ask why can't we say that

"The task of science,as we know , is to discover facts; but a haphazard collection of facts cannot **be said that it constitutes** a science "  Does it make a sense in this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option is not possible. Let's look at a simpler example to see why.

*People say that he drinks.*

*It is said that he drinks.*

*He is said to drink.*

(*)*He is said that he drinks.*

It should be clear that the fourth example is not possible. Now let's look at your sentences in the same way.

*We cannot say that a haphazard collection of facts constitutes a science.*

*It cannot be said that a haphazard collection of facts constitutes a science*.

*A haphazard collection of facts cannot be said to constitute a science.*

(*)*A haphazard collection of facts cannot be said that it constitutes a science*.

Can you see now why the fourth one is not possible?

Comment: Thank you a lot.I think it seems to has something to do with a passive form sentence structure  which I noticed I hadnt given attention before